# How Qt does widget calculate its size?

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt

When I use `QWidget` to design user interface, I am always a little confused regarding its size properties. There's `size policy`, `geometry` and `hintSize`.

I just know the relationship between `size policy` and `hintSize`: the `size policy` is based on `sizehint`. But I don't know other relationship between these properties.

I want to have a widget which size can be automatically changed based on parent or main window size. But I don't know how to use the three properties to finish this goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**geometry:** The current position and size of a widget within its parent. For example, a widget with a geometry of (10, 20, 50, 70) will be located at position (10, 20) within the parent with a width of 50 and a height of 70.

**sizeHint:** (probably what you are referring to by "hintSize") The preferred size in which a widget will be. Override this method to change it.

**size policy:** How the widget will respond when it is placed within a container with dimensions different from its own. Size policies are a combination of:

- [`QSizePolicy::Maximum`] whether a widget can shrink below its `sizeHint`
- [`QSizePolicy::Minimum`] whether a widget can expand above its `sizeHint`, and
- [`QSizePolicy::Expanding`] whether a widget should expand to fill extra available space.

Widgets have both a horizontal and vertical size policy.

---

Nonetheless, you are probably looking for layouts, which automatically resize widgets within their parents based on given rules. For example, to make a widget fill its parent, set the parent's layout to a `QVBoxLayout`, and then add the child widget to the layout. When the parent is resized, the child will be resized to fit automatically.

Comment: Could you please tell me the difference between geometry and sizeHint?If I set geometry value,then the sizeHint will be useless?Can I use this way to comprehend sizehint and geometry?

Comment: Size policies are only used by Qt when a widget is within a layout. Therefore, a widget will ignore its size policy when not in a layout. Geometry will work on widgets both in layouts and not in layouts. However, a widget in a layout will recalculate its geometry when the parent is resized, so manually set geometries will not work effectively in this case. When a widget is not in a layout, its size hint will be its initial size, and any subsequent calls to `setGeometry` will override its current size.